# Disable NO_BUTTON from JOptionPane Java if a condition is true

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I used showConfirmDialog method from JOptionPane with the options: YES_NO_CANCEL. How can I have access and disable NO_BUTTON if a condition is true? 
Thank you!

Comment: *"if a condition is true"*  Tell us more.  Is this 'condition' known prior to showing the option pane?  Does it change based on selections in the open option pane?  What is the condition, exactly?

Comment: You can specify your own buttons as in [my example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476214/878469) and handle everything that happens when they are pressed, disabling some of them included. If you insist on using showConfirmDialog, then extending is probably the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just show a different type of dialog if said condition is true?

```
if(canCancel)
{
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(" blah blah blah ");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(" blah blah blah ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is impossible without overriding `JOptionPane`.

Try searching for `swinglabs` or `jGoodies` libraries for Java. They have built in type for the thing you need.

Comment: and if I override JOptionPane how can I do it? Thank you