# How to close a JDialog through JButtons

Tags: java, jbutton, jdialog

I am making a method that gives the user three choices and returns the one they click, right now the method kinda works I click one of the options and if I click the close button it returns the last clicked.  I want to to make it so that the dialog closes when you click one of the options

```
public E drawThreeForDecision()
{
    ArrayList<E> c = new ArrayList<E>();
    Component[] options = new Component[3];
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++)
    {
        final int loop = iii;
        c.add((E) drawCard());
        JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((GameEntity) c.get(iii)).getEntityImage()));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {

            }
        });
        options[iii] = button;
    }
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Please select a card", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, options[0]);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "DECISION TIME!");
    dialog.setVisible(true);;
    if (pane.getValue() instanceof Integer)
        return (E) pane.getValue();
    return c.get(0);
}
```

If anyone can help me with this or suggest a better solution it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476214/878469).

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setVisible(true);

Comment: AH! You gave me a brainwave, if I declare the JOptionPane and JDialog object at the start of the class I can then call the dispose method  
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use     ***dialog.dispose();*** inside the *actionPerformed()* method.